# When should one use element.isPresent() over ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(element)?

Tags: protractor

While end-to-end testing our app, I am often waiting for a state transition (a modal to close, a button to appear, etc). Blind experimentation has led me to sometimes use `browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(someElement)`, and other times use `browser.wait(someElement.isPresent())`.

To me, the names imply they're interchangeable. But it isn't so. Is there something about the situations in which I use these that will help me tell which to use when?

Comment: There are some good answers already so I won't add one that repeats everything they've said. Basically, I use `.isPresent()` when I need to check that an element is present in the DOM when I expect it to be. I use `.presenceOf()` when I need to wait for an element to become present in the DOM. Meaning, it was not there previously but I did something that will make it present eventually. Like you mentioned, waiting for a button or field to appear/disappear or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, I have used `element.isPresent()` for when I do not want to specifically verify something. For example I can write:

```
element.isPresent().then(function(elm){
    if(elm) { //if the element is present, do something  }
    else    { //if the element is not present, do something else  }
});
```

But if I **need** some element to be present/visible/clickable in order to execute an expect or something else, then I would use a `browser.wait(EC.presenceOf/visibilityOf/elementToBeClickable(element))`

It also depends on the element you need to wait for. If its a button that you need to click, you'll have to use `elementToBeClickable`

Answer (score 1):

If we take a look at the code, we will see that [isPresent](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.4.1/lib/element.ts) method looks like this

```
  isPresent(): wdpromise.Promise<boolean> {
    return this.count().then((count) => {
      return count > 0;
    });
  }
```

While [presenceOf](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.4.1/lib/expectedConditions.ts) is dependent on `isPresent`

```
 presenceOf(elementFinder: ElementFinder): Function {
    return elementFinder.isPresent.bind(elementFinder);
  };
```

In fact they are doing the same. But note, that ExpectedConditions operators, like `not`, `or` and etc. expecting `ExpectedConditions` function as an argument which`presenceOf` is, while `isPresent` is not.

Sometimes you need more complicated conditions, than to check that one particular element is present `browser.wait(someElement.isPresent())`. This is where `ExpectedConditions` constructions are incredibly useful and this is where you would need `presenceOf`.