# What is the difference between ExpectedConditions.presenceOf and element.isPresent

Tags: selenium, protractor, e2e-testing

I have been testing with `element.IsPresent()`, for some reason my test start failing when trying to do `browser.wait(element(by.id('id').IsPresent())`. It never get away from the wait, even the element being present.

I started using  the code with `protractor.ExpectedConditions` and it start working.  just want to know what is the difference between one and the other.

Here is the code with the Expected Conditions.

`const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
const ele = element(by.id('id'));
return browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(ele));`

What is the main difference between one and the other? I have search in google but haven't found a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55051309/10657522) answer on another question you will see that both `presenceOf()` and `isPresent()` are almost entirely the same. The primary difference being that `presenceOf()` *wraps* around `isPresent()` and returns a `Function` rather than a `Promise`.

So why is this important? Well it has to do with how `browser.wait()` works. If we take a look at the [docs](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) we can see that it:

> Schedules a command to wait for a condition to hold or promise to be resolved.

This means that if you pass a `Promise` to `browser.wait()` it will only wait until that `Promise` is *resolved* before continuing on and executing further commands (it doesn't necessarily matter if it resolved true or false). Whereas if you pass a `Function` to it, it will wait until that condition "holds" before continuing.

Additionally, you can specify a custom timeout parameter for the `browser.wait()` method. If you do not specify a timeout it will default to 30 seconds according to the docs. I believe this is why you felt that the wait never resolves when using `isPresent()` (it was likely just taking 30 seconds).

What I would suggest to do is use `isPresent()` when you *expect* an element to be present at a specific moment in time and use `presenceOf()` when you want to wait for an element to be or become present.

Here's an example of how I would use the two:

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
const ele = element(by.id('id'));

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(ele), 5000); // Waits a maximum of 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds)
expect(ele.isPresent()).toBe(true); // Expects this element to be present **right now**
```

Comment: ...or you could use `.presenceOf()` all the time and not have to worry about slight mistimings. :)

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify... what I meant was that I think that a lot of people would use `.isPresent()` (by itself) and it might work at first but fails intermittently depending on the timing of everything. Rather than start with `.isPresent()`, instead start with what you have... a wait and then check `.isPresent()` to avoid the cases where the site is slightly slower than usual.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying but just to be sure: Are you suggesting to always `browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elem))` and thereafter do an `expect(elem.isPresent()).toBe(true)`?

Comment: If so, I would say that I agree with you but only if the element under test is one that is *expected* to sometimes not be present in the DOM (such as those that are inserted under certain conditions). But if we're talking about an element that is *expected* to always be present then there's no need to ever run a `browser.wait()` before-hand. Sure, it doesn't do any harm to put it in there anyway but I am personally against writing what I call 'just-in-case code'. Please excuse me if I misunderstood again.

Comment: I just meant that it's helpful to always add at least a brief wait before performing an action on an element. It may pass 95% of the time with no wait but that 5% is going to be annoying... causes extra investigations, lowers reliability, lowers trust, etc. ... so just add the wait and bring it up to near 100%. I wouldn't consider that 'just-in-case-code', I would consider it to be insurance.

Comment: I get what you're saying and I understand that it would be frustrating to have such an inconsistency and why it can be tempting to add 'waits' in everywhere to make tests more consistent. In fear of making this post too opinion-based I won't offer my opinion any more than I already have. I hope you understand. Thank you very much for your input!